# use of undeclared identifier 'prepareForSegue'

Tags: objective-c

I'm having two issues with the below code. First, the userCategorySave Parse cloud function is supposed to run when the submit button is tapped, however there are no signs of it running in my logs.

The other problem is an error I'm getting that states `use of undeclared identifier 'prepareForSegue'`. I was under the impression that `prepareForSegue` was a standard part of an iOS app, and didn't need to be declared. Why is this class in particular giving me this error?

```
#import "CriteriaViewController.h"

@interface CriteriaViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *itemConditionSegment;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *itemLocationSegment;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *submitButton;


@end

@implementation CriteriaViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

}





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)itemConditionSegment:(id)sender{


    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (selectedSegment == 0) {

        self.itemCondition = @"new";

    }
    else{
        self.itemCondition = @"any";
    }

}

- (IBAction)itemLocationSegment:(id)sender {



    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if (selectedSegment == 0) {

        self.itemLocation = @"US";

    }
    else if (selectedSegment == 1) {

        self.itemLocation = @"WorldWide";

    }


}



//add all the info to users respective new category object
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender
{
    if (self.minPrice.text.length > 0 && self.maxPrice.text.length > 0)

    {

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"userCategorySave"
                           withParameters:@{@"categoryId": self.chosenCategory,
                                              @"minPrice": self.minPrice.text,
                                              @"maxPrice": self.maxPrice.text,
                                         @"itemCondition": self.itemCondition,
                                          @"itemLocation": self.itemLocation,}
                                         block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {

                                             if (!error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Criteria successfuly saved.");

                                                     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue" sender:self];

                                             }
                                         }];

    }




- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

}


@end
```

Comment: Are you sure submitButton is connected in IB and that the `self.minPrice.text.length > 0 && self.maxPrice.text.length > 0` will be true? `prepareForSegue` is not part of every iOS app but a method of `UIViewController`. The error comes from the missing `}` after the `submitButton` method.

Comment: Wow how silly of me. This solved the prepareForSegue error. As for submitButton, I control-dragged it into the implementation as can be seen in the property up top. However, the method has a non-filled in circle to the left of it, as can be seen here: http://i.imgur.com/kE07b4V.png . Does this mean it's not correctly connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not close the `}` correctly.so add one brase in the above method  `prepare for seque`.